# different outputs using hashbytes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hashbytes

I have a simple table for testing `HASH PASSWORDS` 
i have 2 columns PWD & HASHED_PWD. let's say in PWD i have password '111' in HASHED_PWD I used this query to add hashed password '111':

```
declare @hashThis nvarchar(150);
select @hashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(150),(SELECT PWD FROM Customers where CustomerID='cust-111'));
update Customers set HASHED_PWD=HASHBYTES('md5',@hashThis) where CustomerID='cust-111';
```

the result is this:

```
칮핏섛鐓鈦絣䮝ຆ
```

but when i use the variable to hash '111':

```
declare @hashThis nvarchar(150);
select @hashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(150),(SELECT PWD FROM Customers where CustomerID='cust-111'));
--update Customers set HASHED_PWD=HASHBYTES('md5',@hashThis) where CustomerID='cust-111';
select HASHBYTES('md5',@hashThis) as HASHES;
```

the same query but the result is different. my variable `@hashThis` is:

```
0x6ECE4FD51BC113942692637D9D4B860E
```

my column data type and variable are the same `nvarchar(150)`

why i have different results?

any ideas?

 I used this query to compare and the result is always not correct

```
declare @pwd nvarchar(150);
declare @pwd2 nvarchar(150);
set @pwd=HASHBYTES('md5','111');
set @pwd2=(select HASHED_PWD from Customers where CustomerID='cust-111')
if @pwd=@pwd2
print 'Correct'
else
print 'not correct'
```

Comment: What is the type of `HASHED_PWD`?  This is possibly just a representation issue.

Comment: the same nvarchar(150)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, no it's not a representation issue. i compared both in simple query and the result is always different!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:
I have to use `VARBINARY` data type for `PWD` and `HASHED_PWD` columns.

 and for my variable `@hashThis` as well 

This is what I did. I converted data type for both columns:

```
alter table Customers alter column PWD VARBinary(150)
alter table Customers alter column HashED_PWD VARBinary(150)
```

Then I used a variable to use the same password for test like below:

```
DECLARE @hashThis nvarchar(50);
select @hashThis ='111';
select @hashThis= CONVERT (varbinary(150),@hashThis);
set @hashThis= HASHBYTES('md5',@hashThis);
if @hashThis=(select HASHED_PWD from Customers WHERE CustomerID='cust-111')
print 'Correct'
else
print 'not Correct'
```

and the result is `Correct`.